# Add NOINDEX meta tag to product review

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-enterprise, indexing, meta-tags

I have added **NOINDEX**, and **NOFOLLOW** meta tags to the ***/catalogsearch*** page to remove already indexed pages from search engine indexes. However, I still have trouble removing indexed results for the ***/review*** URL.

The review section is located within the product page, so there is no specific URL for the review page. I'm wondering if there is a way to remove already indexed results for the review section from search engines.

Can anyone suggest a solution for removing already indexed results for the review section in Magento 2?

Thank you.